# How do I make a repeatable index script?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to build a Firebird script that will ensure that a certain index exists and is created correctly.  After a bit of Googling around, I got what seems to be the right syntax:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
execute block as begin
IF (EXISTS(SELECT RDB$INDEX_NAME
  FROM RDB$INDICES
 WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME='TABLE_NAME'
 and RDB$INDEX_NAME = 'INDEX_NAME')) THEN
execute statement 'drop index INDEX_NAME';
end
SET TERM ; ^

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_NAME
  ON TABLE_NAME
  (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3);
```

This will run once, and it works fine.  But if I try to run it a second time, I get a "the index already exists" error, which indicates that the `execute statement` part isn't actually running.

What am I missing? How do I make this script work right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION** clause. The following code works for me:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT RDB$INDEX_NAME FROM RDB$INDICES
    WHERE RDB$RELATION_NAME = '<relation_name>'
      AND RDB$INDEX_NAME = '<index_name>')) THEN
  BEGIN 
    EXECUTE STATEMENT 'drop index <index_name>'
      with autonomous transaction;
  END

  EXECUTE STATEMENT 'create index <index_name> on ...'
    with autonomous transaction;
END
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you *committed* the transaction?

Most relational databases run in a transaction by default. Until you `commit` or `rollback` the transaction is pending. You need to

```
drop index foo

commit -- some implementations use 'commit work' others 'commit transaction'

create index foo on bar ( col_1 , ... , col_n )

commit -- some implementations use 'commit work' others 'commit transaction'
```